# Iterate over multiple generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have multiple generator functions that yield objects which are appended to a list. There's a lot of duplicated code, is there a possibility to minimize this (for Python 3.5+)?

**Generators:**

```
def gen1(obj):
    if obj == 'something':
        yield ValueError()


def gen2(obj):
    if obj == 'else':
        yield ValueError()

value_errors =[]
```

**Working version but duplicated code:**

```
for exc in gen1(obj):
    if isinstance(exc, ValueError):
        value_errors.append(exc)

for exc in gen2(obj):
    if isinstance(exc, ValueError):
        value_errors.append(exc)
```

**Not working but no duplicated code:**

```
generators = [
    gen1(obj),
    gen2(obj)
]

for yielded in generators:
    if isInstance(yielded, ValueError):
        value_errors.append(yielded)
)
```

This does not work because it yields generators not the generator's yielded value. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Why do you need generators that yield a single object?

Comment: Simplified generators for the example, they might yield much more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `itertools.chain()`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Example:

```
for yielded in itertools.chain(gen1(obj), gen2(obj)):
    if isinstance(yielded, ValueError):
        value_errors.append(yielded)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[obj for generator in generators for obj in generator]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for yielded in generators:
    for _yielded in yielded:
        if isinstance(_yielded, ValueError):
            value_errors.append(_yielded)
```